# How to resolve class interdependence in my C++ code?

Tags: c++, class-design, class

In my C++ project, I have two classes, `Particle` and `Contact`. In the `Particle` class, I have a member variable `std::vector<Contact> contacts` which contains all contacts of a `Particle` object, and corresponding member functions `getContacts()` and `addContact(Contact cont)`. Thus, in "Particle.h", I include "Contact.h".

In the `Contact` class, I would like to add code to the constructor for `Contact` that will call `Particle::addContact(Contact cont)`, so that `contacts` is updated for both the `Particle` objects between which the `Contact` object is being added. Thus, I would have to include "Particle.h" in "Contact.cpp".

My question is whether or not this is acceptable/good coding practice and, if not, what would be a better way to implement what I am trying to achieve (simply put, automatically updating the list of contacts for a specific particle whenever a new contact is created).

---

These classes will be tied together by a `Network` class that will have N particles (`std::vector<Particle> particles`) and Nc contacts (`std::vector<Contact> contacts`). But I wanted to be able to have functions like `particles[0].getContacts()` – is it okay to have such functions in the `Particle` class in this case, or is there a better association "structure" in C++ for this purpose (of two related classes being used in another class).

---

I may need a perspective shift here in how I am approaching this. Since the two classes are connected by a `Network` class object, is it typical code/class organization to have connectivity information entirely controlled by the `Network` object (in that a Particle object should not be aware of its contacts and, consequently, it should not have a `getContacts()` member function). Then, in order to know what contacts a specific particle has, I would need to obtain that information through the `Network` object (e.g., using `network.getContacts(Particle particle)`).

Would it be less typical (perhaps even discouraged) C++ class design for a Particle object to have that knowledge, as well (i.e., have multiple ways to access that information -- through either the Network object or the Particle object, whichever seems more convenient)?

Comment: Here's a talk from cppcon 2017 - The Three Layers of Headers : https://youtu.be/su9ittf-ozk

Comment: Questions that contain words like "best," "better" and "acceptable" are unanswerable unless you can **state your specific criteria of evaluation.**

Comment: Thanks for the edit, though changing your wording to "typical" just makes it a question of popularity.  There are reasons why coding is done one way or another, and while popularity can be an indication that a technique is "good" (for some definition of "good"), it can also be an indication of cargo-culting.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I removed "better" and "bad" in my final section. I suppose I am asking for the typical (perhaps even favored/encouraged) approach when you have a `Network` class object that contains `Particle` objects and `Contact` objects. With that base knowledge, I can then try to assess whether or not it fits with my specific needs, which are still being explored/developed as I go along in the project.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I suppose that I am new enough to writing C++ projects completely from scratch that I am fine with learning what is "typical" and "popular". Hopefully I will gain enough insight at some point to be able to realize why another implementation is actually better, but for now, I just want to make sure I am not approaching this in a completely bone-headed way!

Comment: After You have updated your question, it is changing scope. ... Now you are asking about the architecture of your application, when previously it was about a technical issue.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are two parts in your question.

The first part is the organization of C++ header files and source files. This is solved by using **forward declaration** and the separation of the class declaration (putting them in the header file) and method body (putting them in the source file). Furthermore, in some cases one can apply the [Pimpl idiom ("pointer to implementation")](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl) to solve harder cases. Use shared-ownership pointers (`shared_ptr`), single-ownership pointers (`unique_ptr`), and non-owning pointers (raw pointer, i.e. the "asterisk") according to best practices.

The second part is how to model objects that are inter-related in the form of a **graph**. General graphs that are **not** DAGs (directed acyclic graphs) don't have a natural way of expressing tree-like ownership. Instead, the nodes and connections are all metadata that belong to a single graph object. In this case, it is not possible to model the node-connection relationship as aggregations. Nodes don't "own" connections; connections don't "own" nodes. Instead, they are associations, and both nodes and connections are "owned by" the graph. The graph provides query and manipulation methods that operate on the nodes and connections.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I actually do have a Network class that will have N particles and Nc contacts. But I wanted to be able to have functions like `particles[0].getContacts()` – are you suggesting in your last paragraph that I shouldn't have such functions in the `Particle` class, or that the current structure is okay because they are inherently related/associated through `Network`? Is there a better association "structure" in C++ in this case?

Comment: Generally that the Network is responsible for knowing about relationships between objects. If you use an adjacency list, for example, the particle `network.particle[p]` would have a corresponding `network.contacts[p]` with the indices of its contacts. Otherwise, the Network and the Particle are somehow both tracking the same information.

Comment: @Useless Yeah, that's where I'm unsure of how to proceed. So you are saying that the `Particle` object shouldn't be aware of its contacts (so I shouldn't have a `getContacts()` member function), and that that information should only come from within the `Network` object? Would it be bad C++ class design for a `Particle` object to have that knowledge (i.e., have multiple ways to access that information -- through either the `Network` object or the `Particle` object, whichever seems more convenient)? The latter seems to make more sense to me, but maybe I need to change my perspective on this.

Comment: @PhysicsCodingEnthusiast: The problem with a `Particle` knowing anything about `Contact`s or `Network`s is that it ties you to a specific way of representing that relationship. All three classes may have to agree. If instead the `Network` is the only one who knows or cares, that's only one class that needs to change if you decide another representation is better.

Comment: @cHao Okay, this makes sense. So `Particle` and `Contact` should be completely separate, and the association between them is defined by the `Network` object. Just to be completely sure, this is (probably) what @rwong meant when he/she wrote, "both nodes and connections are "owned by" the graph. The graph provides query and manipulation methods that operate on the nodes and connections.", right?

Comment: @PhysicsCodingEnthusiast: Basically, yes.

Answer (score 5):

If I got you right, the same contact object belongs to more than one particle object, since it represents some kind of physical contact between two or more particles, right?

So the first thing which I think is questionable is why `Particle` has a member variable `std::vector<Contact>`? It should be a `std::vector<Contact*>` or a `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Contact> >` instead. `addContact` then should have different signature like `addContact(Contact *cont)` or `addContact(std::shared_ptr<Contact> cont)` instead.

This makes it unnecessary to include "Contact.h" in "Particle.h", a forward declaration of `class Contact` in "Particle.h", and an include of "Contact.h" in "Particle.cpp" will be enough.

Then the question about the constructor. You want something like

```
 Contact(Particle &p1, Particle &p2)
 {
      p1.addContact(this);
      p2.addContact(this);
 }
```

Right? This design is ok, as long as your program does always knows the related particles at the point in time when a contact object has to be created.

Note, if you go the `std::vector<Contact*>` route, you have to invest some  thoughts about the lifetime and ownership of the `Contact` objects. No particle "owns" its contacts, a contact will probably have to be deleted only if both related `Particle` objects are destructed.  Using `std::shared_ptr<Contact>` instead will solve this problem for you automatically. Or you let a "surrounding context" object take the ownership of particles and contacts (like suggested by @rwong), and manage their lifetime.

Comment: I don't see the benefit of `addContact(const std::shared_ptr<Contact> &cont)` over `addContact(std::shared_ptr<Contact> cont)`?

Comment: @Caleth: this was discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310737/shared-ptr-by-reference-or-by-value - "const" is not really important here, but passing objects by reference (and scalars by value) is the standard idiom in C++ .

Comment: Many of those answers seem to be from a pre-`move` paradigm

Comment: @Caleth: ok, to keep all nitpickers happy, I changed this quite unimportant part of my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the response. In regards to using the objects vs. pointers-to-the-objects in vectors, is it simply for memory management / not creating copies of potentially large `Contact`objects? Because from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22146094/why-should-i-use-a-pointer-rather-than-the-object-itself?rq=1 it seems that pointers are overused in C++, and I'm wondering if that could potentially be the case here (not suggesting this – actually asking because I don't know).

Comment: @PhysicsCodingEnthusiast: no, this is foremost about making `particle1.getContacts()` and `particle2.getContacts()` delivering the same `Contact` object representing the physical contact between `particle1` and `particle2`, and not two different objects. Of course, one could try to design the system in a way it does not matter if there are two `Contact` objects available at the same time representing the same physical contact. This would involve to make `Contact` immutable, but are you sure that this is what you want?

Comment: @DocBrown Ah, yes, I see that quite obviously now. Also, in terms of lifetime and ownership you brought up in the last paragraph, I do have a `Network` class that plays the role of a "surrounding context" (see my edit to the original question). In this case, are there modifications to the implementation that you've suggested, or does it still apply? Thanks!

Comment: @PhysicsCodingEnthusiast: no modifications needed from what I see. But since only you know your use case in detail, you need to decide by yourself how to implement object creation and destruction in your application.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, what you describe is a very acceptable way of ensuring that every `Contact` instance is in the list of contacts of a `Particle`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I had read some suggestions that having a pair of interdependent classes is to be avoided (for instance, in "C++ Design Patterns and Derivatives Pricing" by M. S. Joshi), but apparently that is not necessarily correct? Out of curiosity, is there perhaps another way of implementing this automatic updating without needing interdependence?

Comment: @PhysicsCodingEnthusiast: Having interdependent classes creates all kinds of difficulties and you should try to avoid them. But sometimes, two classes are so closely related to each other that removing interdependence between them causes more problems than the interdependence itself.

Answer (score 0):

What you have done is correct.

Another way... If the aim is to ensure that every `Contact` is in a list, then you could:

- block creation of `Contact` (private constructors),
- forward declare `Particle` class,
- make `Particle` class a friend of `Contact`,
- in `Particle` create a factory method which creates a `Contact`

Then you don't have to include `particle.h` in `contact`

Comment: Thanks for the response! That seems like a useful way of implementing this. Just wondering, with my edit to the initial question regarding the `Network` class, does that change the suggested structure, or would it still be the same?

Comment: After You have updated your question, it is changing scope. ... Now you are asking about the architecture of your application, when previously it was about a technical issue.

Answer (score 0):

Another option you might consider is making the Contact constructor that accepts a Particle reference templated. This will allow a Contact to add itself to any container that implements `addContact(Contact)`.

```
template<class Container>
Contact(/*parameters*/, Container& container)
{
  container.addContact(*this);
}
```