# Using vectors of shared pointers to objects in my C++ code to prevent object duplication

Tags: c++, class-design, class, c++11, smart-pointer

In my C++ project, I have three classes, `Particle`, `Contact`, and `Network`. The `Network` class will have N particles (`std::vector<Particle> particles`) and Nc contacts (`std::vector<Contact> contacts`). `Particle` objects will each have a number of contacts, represented by `Contact` objects, and contacts are shared by pairs of particles.

It will be necessary for me to know what contacts a specific particle has, and I have decided to be able to obtain that information through the `Network` object (e.g., using `network.getContacts(Particle particle)`).

My question can be broken into two parts:

**First**, what would be an efficient and community-recommended way to store the contacts for each particle?

I believe that I can either create a vector of vector of shared pointers to `Contact` objects, `vector<vector<shared_ptr<Contact>>> prtContacts` (where I have left off `std::` for ease of viewing), so that `prtContacts[i]` will contain a vector of shared pointers to the contacts of the `i`th particle. It has been suggested that using `shared_ptr` in this context is useful, as it will ensure that I am not creating duplicate `Contact` objects for two particles with a shared contact. Is there an alternative method that would make more sense?

**Second**, if I do end up creating `prtContacts` as defined above, what is the best way to initialize it? My current thinking is to have an initial loop that initializes `std::vector<Contact> contacts` with the Nc contacts and then have a second loop that initializes `prtContacts` with shared pointers to the Contacts. Is that reasonable or, again, are there alternative, more efficient, approaches?

Thank you!

---

**Some additional information:**

The number of particles, N, will range from `O(10^1)` to perhaps `O(10^4)`. The number of contacts per particle will most likely not exceed 6-7, but will be allowed to vary. Each contact will have a position and contact force (2-component vector) associated with it, and both positions and contact forces will be allowed to vary during the course of simulations (e.g., Monte Carlo simulations).

Comment: What is your typical access pattern for the most compute intensive steps of the algorithms you're applying to this data structure?

Comment: @Omnifarious I added some additional information to the question that is hopefully helpful. But I will want to use this for various simulations (e.g., Monte Carlo) where I am changing certain positions and/or contact forces of the contacts or positions of the particles at every iteration.

Comment: Will the simulation engine basically loop through the contacts and use the information to update the associated particles? Or will you be looping through the particles? The thing you loop through should be allocated in all contiguous memory. Basically as members of a `vector` or something like that.

Comment: @Omnifarious The `Network` class will ideally be flexible and allow for both cases (depending on which is the main control parameter – particle positions or contact forces). That's why I have defined both as `vector`s. But in terms of having a list of contacts per particle, knowing the extra information I have provided, is my implementation outlined in my question okay (with shared pointers being replaced with regular pointers, as you suggested)? Or is more information still needed? Thanks for the continued help!

Comment: Yes. In fact, you should very definitely **not** use shared pointers in this case. This is because the `vector<Contact>` holds Contact objects, not pointers to them. So it's the sole manager of their lifetime. In fact, you should use indexes into this array, not pointers at all, because this array might move around as you add and remove contacts.

Comment: @Omnifarious I might be mistaken, but isn't the fact that the number of contacts, Nc, isn't fixed, and that contacts can change mean that we should use pointers rather than indices? Unless you mean a unique contact index that I assign to each contact,, and not the index in the vector...

Comment: You've got a few choices. If you have a vector and you have pointers into the middle of it, any operation that changes the size of the vector (push_back, insert, remove, etc...) will invalidate all of those pointers. If you have indexes, then only operations that remove things from the middle of the vector and squish up all the remaining elements will invalidate them. If neither choice is acceptable, you need to have a dequeue or list instead. And then pointers will not be invalidated and indexes are a bad idea.

Comment: And, of course, if you use a list, then you completely destroy any locality of reference advantage you have.

Comment: @Omnifarious Then I think the best way forward might be to assign a unique contact ID/index (or a unique pair corresponding to the particle IDs) to each contact so that it doesn't matter where it is located in the vector... Though that might result in always having to rely on `if` statements to find the correct contact?

Comment: You can use the `find_if` and other '_if` algorithms. This will slow accessing a contact from a particle down considerably.  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm

Comment: @Omnifarious Thanks for all the replies! You've given me quite a bit of options and advice. Would you mind augmenting your answer with a bit of an overview/summary for future (viewers') reference? If you don't want to / have time to, I totally understand. In any case, thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The right solution will depend a lot on your non-functional requirements. How many particles will you typically have? How many contacts does a particle typically have? How much is a network updated, and in what ways? How fast does it need to be?

I suggest referring to objects by index if you can and then particle contacts can be a list of contact indexes. If a particle typically has a small number of contacts then instead of a `vector` I suggest using something that is optimized for a small number of elements like `boost::container::small_vector`, `absl::inlined_vector`, `folly::small_vector` or `llvm::SmallVector`.

```
using ParticleContacts = boost::container::small_vector<int, 12>;

class Network {
  std::vector<Particle> particles;
  std::vector<Contact> contacts;
  std::vector<ParticleContacts> particle_contacts;
 public:
  ParticleContacts getParticleContacts(int particle_index) const {
    return particle_contacts.at(particle_index);
  }
  Contact getContact(int contact_index) const {
    return contacts.at(contact_index);
  }
  //...
};
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/uk88K17aKwtRc6MX).

**Edit:** If you have to be able to delete from the middle of the `vector` of contacts then using an index will not work. I would seriously consider if you can change your algorithm so that this is not necessary. Not only does it invalidate pointers, iterators and indexes but it also is quite inefficient because all the contacts after the deletion have to be moved. Perhaps, for example, you can just leave orphaned contacts until the end of the simulation with no connection to a particle. Anyway, if you really need to be able to delete from the middle of the list of contacts perhaps a `vector` is not the best data structure and you should prefer something like a linked list. The advantage of a linked list is you can do quick deletion from the middle and also pointers to contacts in the list are not invalidated by inserts or deletions so your list of particle contacts can be raw pointers. The downside is it is much slower and does not allow random access.

```
using ParticleContacts = boost::container::small_vector<Contact*, 12>;

class Network {
  std::vector<Particle> particles;
  std::forward_list<Contact> contacts;
  std::vector<ParticleContacts> particle_contacts;
 public:
  ParticleContacts getParticleContacts(int particle_index) const {
    return particle_contacts.at(particle_index);
  } 
  void addParticle(const Particle& particle) {
    particles.push_back(particle);
    particle_contacts.emplace_back();
  } 
  Contact* addParticleContact(int particle_index_1, int particle_index_2) {
    contacts.emplace_front();
    particle_contacts.at(particle_index_1).push_back(&contacts.front());
    particle_contacts.at(particle_index_2).push_back(&contacts.front());  
    return &contacts.front();
  }
};
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/NoFUvy5IJSkn9CXu).

Alternatively, you could use `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Contact>>`. Raw pointers to the contact won't be invalidated by insertions and deletions. It has the advantage of allowing random access but the disadvantage of being slower at insertions and deletions: [Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Tr70m8OunNXJXFnV)

The right choice will depend on how the data is typically accessed by the simulation.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I updated my initial question with some more information – please let me know if you need anything else. The one thing with contact indices is that won't they change as contacts are added and removed (the number of contacts, Nc, is not necessarily fixed). In that case, aren't pointers better than indices?

Comment: Unless you mean a unique contact index that I assign to each contact, and not the index in the vector...

Comment: You can use indices if you are adding contacts to the end but, yes, indices won't work if you are deleting from the middle of the list of contacts. But pointers to a contact in a `vector<Contact>` is even worse. Inserting or deleting may invalidate these pointers. You would have to use a different type of container or use something like `vector<unique_ptr<Contact>>` which will introduce some overhead.

Comment: I unfortunately don't think I'll be able to use `unique_ptr` because two particles will need to have pointers to the same `Contact` object. And apparently, according to Omnifarious, `shared_ptr` is not to be used either unless there are no other options. So would you recommend having a unique ID for each contact that I can use to generate the lists of contacts for each particle? If so, is there a way to efficiently and easily find the correct contact in the vector of contacts (other than relying on `if` statements, etc.)? Thank you!

Comment: You only need to use `shared_ptr` if you need shared ownership. If I understand things correctly the network can have unique ownership of the contacts and then the list of particle contacts can be non owning references like raw pointers. But even `unique_ptr` might be too much overhead.

Comment: I like this approach, it is a good start. Letting the network take the ownership of pointers and contacts is probably the easiest way to avoid any ownership problems, and it is a fast approach, too. It eliminiates the need for `shared_ptr`, as I wrote in my [former answer here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/360430/9113). So is it better to use indexes or raw pointers for storing the references between contacts and particles? Indexes have one big advantage: if you want to copy a whole network, you do not have to write you own copy constructor.

Comment: ... If, however, during the simulation huge amount of contact objects are newly created and vanish again, you (@PhysicsCodingEnthusiast) will probably have to invest more thoughts here - this solution handles only a growing amount of contacts, if Contact objects are not needed any more, they will be freed from memory when the whole network will be deleted, not earlier. But as I said, it is a good start.

Comment: @ChrisDrew Thanks for the updates and the working examples in each case. Really helpful to be able to see actual implementations. I especially like the `unique_ptr` approach. @DocBrown There are some instances where the contacts will be fixed, but I can envision scenarios where I will want the contacts to be formed and removed quite readily. Perhaps adjacency matrices would be better in that case?

Comment: One last question that I don't believe has been addressed yet: would it be recommended at all to use unique contact IDs to store a list of each particle's contacts? And then I can obtain any needed information/data by picking out the `Contact` objects from `contacts` matching those IDs. This would not involve the actual indices of the vector, however, since those *may* not be fixed. Or are the approaches that you've outlined (say, with `unique_ptr`s) more efficient/performant overall?

Comment: @PhysicsCodingEnthusiast: an adjacency matrix would only make sense here when implemented as a sparse matrix (since I guess you do not want to reserve memory for 10^8 contacts if 10^4 * 7 would be enough, I guess?) But since sparse matrices are implemented typically with row or column lists, this leads effectively to the same solution shown in this answer.

Comment: ... using unique IDs is another possibility here. If you go that route, use an ID for particles as well as for contacts and use a hashmap container for both, where the ID is the key. That will allow fast insert and deletion as well.

Comment: @DocBrown Thanks for the reply. Are there any reasons that I wouldn't want to use the hashmap container (I'm assuming `std::unordered_map`)? As it seems right now, I will probably choose between the `unique_ptr` implementation and the hashmap implementation depending on efficiency/performance and also ease of implementation. Really appreciate it!

Comment: @PhysicsCodingEnthusiast: I think it is time you start coding and implement some of your use cases, this will show you the problems you need to solve (or not) much better than a theoretical discussion here.

Comment: @DocBrown Of course; I've been coding alongside these discussions. Some of the additional use cases won't become clear until further analysis of the data, which is why I wasn't able to definitively list them here.

Answer (score 3):

So, this really depends on the access patterns you anticipate. First, `shared_ptr` comes at a potentially large cost in a multi-threaded program. Incrementing and decrementing the reference counts will cause processor cache invalidation on other CPUs. This will cause those operations to be slightly more expensive, and it will cause a lot of cache thrashing if those objects are being accessed in any way from multiple threads because even read access to bytes near the reference count will result in a very costly main memory fetch after the reference count has been updated.

Now, one way you could mitigate this is to not use `make_shared` like you're told to. This will result in the reference count being allocated separately from the object. But that potentially moves the cache problem elsewhere.

The various kinds of pointer are about expressing ownership. Does the object **really** have shared ownership? Or is it more appropriate to think of the Network as a whole as owning the object? If it's the latter, it might make more sense to store bare pointers and simply have a few `vector` objects (one per type) in the Network that hold `unique_ptr`s to all of the graph elements.

Is the number of contacts per particle bounded at a reasonably small number? If so, it might make sense to use a fixed size `array` that stores a list of bare pointers to contacts and have a Network object that actually owns all of the objects.

I'm sure there are more considerations. And my primary focus here has been on performance rather than some abstract notion of the 'right' way to do things. Perhaps something other than performance is your primary goal. Though, if that's the case, why are you using C++ here?

Comment: Thanks for the response! I can start responding here; if there is too much information, please let me know, and I can add the relevant portions to my question. The `Network` object should own all particles and contacts, and I will have a vector of Nc `Contact` objects called `contacts` (see my question). But if `contacts[i]` is between `particles[j]` and `particles[k]`, and I want that information to be obtainable by `network.getContacts(particles[j])` and `network.getContacts(particles[k])`, won't that require two pointers to the same object (which is the purpose of `shared_ptr`, right?)?

Comment: The number of contacts per particle should never exceed 6-7, but the number is not fixed (so a `vector` is preferable). I definitely care about performance, which I usually take to mean "right" in the context of C++!

Comment: No, `shared_ptr` should not be your goto whenever you have two pointers pointing to the same thing. It's about lifetime management. If you can't think of a sane way to manage the lifetime of an object than to have shared ownership semantics, use `shared_ptr`. Otherwise, don't. For example, I use a reference counted pointer in something where I have buffers that can be built out of fragments from other buffers. I don't copy any parts of the buffer, I refer to them from buffers that logically contain them. shared_ptr is the only way there.

Comment: Okay, so suppose that everything in my post is the same, except that I use regular pointers rather than shared pointers. Do my approaches to both questions make sense, or are there more efficient/performant approaches? Next, if I use regular pointers, should I have two pointers to the same `Contact` object, or should I try to use the same pointer for the vector of contacts for both particles (if that's even possible)? Thanks!

Comment: @PhysicsCodingEnthusiast - Two pointers to the same Contact. Leave it up to the Network to make sure that the pointers get deleted from the appropriate Particles before the Contact is deleted.

Comment: @PhysicsCodingEnthusiast - And you never answered the question I asked on your main post, and that question is actually pretty important. It determines what your Network class (in particular) should look like, and it also determines just how important it is to not do dynamic allocation for the list of pointers to contacts stored in each particle.

Answer (score 1):

I'd largely echo Chris' answer but with some possible deviations. The ultimate thing I'd echo wholeheartedly is to store indices to your particles and contacts, stored in big sequences like a couple of big vector pers network.

However, one part where I disagree is that you *can* use indices and a random-access sequence and still have constant-time removals (with a super small constant) without index invalidation if you use an indexed free list/holes strategy. If particles die, then you can remove them in constant-time and reclaim/insert in constant-time without using any extra memory, like so:

[image]

... where `union Nodes nodes[n]` might be `std::vector<union Node>`. It takes a little more elbow grease if `Particle` or `Contact` isn't trivially constructible or destructible (making a proper container in C++ for non-PODs is a bit of a PITA with placement new, aligned storage, and manual dtor invocations). Hopefully they are, as generally can be the case for this type of data.

> First, what would be an efficient and community-recommended way to
>   store the contacts for each particle?

Assuming it's efficient to just simulate and gather the contacts for all particles at once (which is often the case in many simulations), short answer:

```
// Stores all the contacts between particles. Each per-particle 
// contact list begins with a count followed by the indices to each
// contact.
std::vector<int> contact_data;

// Stores an index into the contact data for each particle.
std::vector<int> contacts;
```

To get the contacts for the nth particle, we do:

```
// Fetch the index into the contact data for the nth particle.
const int cd_index = contacts[n];

// Fetch the number of contacts.
const int num = contact_data[cd_index];

// Fetch a pointer to the array of contact indices.
const int* indices = contact_data.data() + cd_index + 1;
```

And now you have the indices of the contacts and the number of them for the nth particle. You can clear the list and compute it for each time step. You can also do it multithreaded with a bit of work (gather the contacts for ranges of particles in each thread locally, then merge the results into the two vectors at the end).

> `network.getContacts(Particle particle)`

If you follow the suggestion to use indices, the above turns to this:

```
// Returns the number of contacts and a pointer to the array
// of contact indices for the particle indexed by 'particle_index'.
std::pair<int, const int*> network.getContacts(int particle_index)
```

... you can use something a bit nicer than `std::pair`, like your own structure or class.

**SmallVectors and the Like**

Now using something like `boost::small_vector` or `llvm::SmallVector` is a very good solution, far superior to requiring a heap allocation for every particle as would be the case if you used `std::vector` for each one. Chris' answer is already really good. But if you want to persistently store the contacts, these small buffer optimizations start to get a little bit explosive in memory use which can translate to extra cache misses (they are pretty great for short-lived storage though on the stack), which is why I recommend just a big old vector of integers instead with the assumption that your simulation might be better off computing all the contacts at once rather than computing them on demand in `getContacts` (at which point a small vector would start to become much more appropriate).

> [...] in this context is useful, as it will ensure that I am not
>   creating duplicate Contact objects for two particles with a shared
>   contact. Is there an alternative method that would make more sense?

`shared_ptr` is for sharing ownership of a resource and extending its lifetime until all owners release their ownership. To just refer to a resource in multiple places without sharing ownership (which is all you need here) and without duplication of the resource's data, just use plain old indices or pointers. There's a pretty hefty relative overhead to `shared_ptr` used on a per-particle or per-contact basis.

A quick thing in practice using the above techniques (including the indexed free list), and not really "particles" in this case but still agents that collide with each other and a collision list between agents (gathered all at once into two vectors of integers as shown above): 500,000 agents bouncing off of each other, single-threaded, with a good portion of the time spent just plotting pixels and not merely simulating:

[image]

> First, what would be an efficient and community-recommended way to
>   store the contacts for each particle?

If you want to do things very efficiently when the temptation is to store a boatload of tiny lists, ideally store all the data in big sequences, not a bunch of teeny ones. You don't actually need to instantiate a million containers in order to represent the equivalent of a million containers associated to a million elements. You can just use two, for example: one storing all the data and one parallel to the million elements storing starting indices into that data.

This is a general optimization strategy regardless of context, and it addresses a common performance gotcha in languages that provide a lot of convenient containers. Those containers are very efficient for storing a million elements in one container, but not very efficient for storing a million containers with a few elements each. That applies even to the ones that use SBO (small buffer optimizations) like `SmallVector` or `std::string`, because the "small buffer" is either too large (at which point we're wasting memory and getting huge strides from one element to the next) or too small and incurring heap allocations. It's generally not "just right" as is the case if you use one big buffer for all the data.

Note that this answer might be a bit overkill. I'm not really accounting for productivity at all and assuming you have a bit of extra time to deal with the inconvenience of storing everything in one big container and possibly implementing that indexed free list above (I'm not a good person to ask for efficient solutions that can be implemented in 10 minutes... well, I think I can implement these in 10 minutes but only because I've had lots of practice). For VFX it's not uncommon to deal with hundreds of millions of particles, and so I'm often required to use these types of techniques and handroll containers at the bare minimum just to get acceptable performance that won't have users complaining that some other software is faster or having studios switch to simulating with something else on their farms. But I get kinda excited to share some very general techniques to speed things up, and a good one that doesn't get too fancy and hopefully isn't too overkill is just index your elements and store everything in big containers, not a boatload of small ones. I'm actually restraining myself a lot for this answer because there's a lot more I can cover on this topic including an alternative to that indexed free list for the largest scale inputs (far more complex to implement), but I'll stop here!

Answer (score 0):

I have to ask - why are the `Contact`s separate from the `Particle`s? It seems like each `Particle` should contain a list of its contacts. Or if that's not appropriate, maybe another `class` or `struct` that contains a `Particle` and an array (or `vector` or whatever) of `Contact`s. Something like:

```
struct ParticleCollision {
    Particle part;
    std::vector<Contact> contacts;
};
```

The `Network` would then contain a `std::vector` of `ParticleCollision`s.

Comment: That's an interesting suggestion. I wonder if there is any performance concerns with doing such a successive "encapsulation". As for `Particle` objects containing a list of its contacts, the point is that the `Network` object entirely decides the relationship between particles and contacts, so all the related data should be accessible solely through the `Network` object.

Comment: We already discussed this in the OPs former question - no single `Particle` is owner of one `Contact` object, since a contact is associated to two different particles. So when requesting the set of contacts of those two particles, the intersection of those sets should contain the common `Contact` object.